How do I install Electrum Personal Server with bitcoind v28.0 on a RPi4?
I run a Bitcoin Core v28.0 on a Raspberry Pi4 and tried to make Electrum Personal Server work.
I experienced several issues during installation and execution. Any help is very much appreciated. And maybe any one else can use any of the knowledge I gathered.
I ran into these issues:

First it was not possible to install setuptools, I had to use sudo apt install python3-setuptools instead of sudo pip3 install setuptools. Also it was not possible to run pip3 install wheel and pip3 install use .
I had first to create a python virtual environment. I did this with sudo apt install python3-venv,python3 -m venv foobar, source foobar/bin/activate. Finally
I installed with pip install wheel and pip install. instead of pip install --user . then deactivate to exit virtual environment I compiled      bitcoind v28.0 first without wallet. This doesn't work. To win time I downloaded a precompiled version of v28.0.
I created a wallet with bitcoin-cli createwallet "default" "true" "true" "" "true" instead of bitcoin-cli createwallet electrumpersonalserver true true "" false false true because the latter gave the error

"BDB wallet creation is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. In this release it can be re-enabled temporarily with the -deprecatedrpc=create_bdb setting."
I ran electrum-personal-server --rescan ~/.eps/electrum-personal-server/config.cfg this went well.
When I finally run electrum-personal-server ~/.eps/electrum-personal-server/config.cfg I get the error below:
INFO:2024-12-20 09:17:45,652: Starting Electrum Personal Server 0.2.4

INFO:2024-12-20 09:17:45,660: Logging to /tmp/electrumpersonalserver.log

INFO:2024-12-20 09:17:45,809: Displaying first 3 addresses of each master public key:

INFO:2024-12-20 09:17:45,809: Obtaining bitcoin addresses to monitor . . .

INFO:2024-12-20 09:17:45,811: Importing 0 wallets and 1 watch-only addresses into the Bitcoin node

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/bitcoin/.eps/electrum-personal-server/electrum-personal-server-eps-v0.2.4/foobar/bin/electrum-personal-server", line 8, in sys.exit(main()) ^^^^^^

File "/mnt/sda2/electrum-personal-server/electrum-personal-server-eps-v0.2.4/foobar/lib/python3.11/site-packages/electrumpersonalserver/server/common.py", line 481, in main deterministicwallet.import_addresses(rpc, relevant_spks_addrs,

File "/mnt/sda2/electrum-personal-server/electrum-personal-server-eps-v0.2.4/foobar/lib/python3.11/site-packages/electrumpersonalserver/server/deterministicwallet.py", line 29, in import_addresses rpc.call("importmulti", [watchonly_addr_param, {"rescan": False}])

File "/mnt/sda2/electrum-personal-server/electrum-personal-server-eps-v0.2.4/foobar/lib/python3.11/site-packages/electrumpersonalserver/server/jsonrpc.py", line 122, in call raise JsonRpcError(response["error"])

electrumpersonalserver.server.jsonrpc.JsonRpcError: {'code': -4, 'message': 'Only legacy wallets are supported by this command'}

What can I do?

Could you perhaps share what documentation you were following? It sounds like it is very outdated.

I used the documaentation of the developer: https://github.com/chris-belcher/electrum-personal-server.

Finallly solved it myself, the clue was in the last error message. A legacy wallet was required. I stopped bitcond and restarted it using with the option -deprecatedrpc=create_bdb. Now a legacy wallet could be created with: bitcoin-cli createwallet electrumpersonalserver true true "" false false true.
After starting EPS with rescan option EPS was up and runing and listening. However Electrum couldn't still connect. This was because out-of-the-box the certifcate is expired. After creating new certifcate Electrum could connect.
